# how to get coordinates of a linear array

Tags: java, arrays

i am making a game in which i have a 3d map stored int an array int integers:

```
int width = 256;
int height = 256;
int depth = 64;
int[] map = new int[width * height * depth];
```

i need to be able to get get the x, y, z of an index. the current method i came up with is:

```
private int getX(int blockID) {
    return blockID % width;
}

private int getY(int blockID) {
    return (blockID % depth) / height;
}

private int getDepth(int blockID) {
    return blockID / (width * height);
}
```

the methods for getting the x and the depth seem to work but i cannot get the getY() to work correctly and i keep getting and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException like the one below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at game.Level.updateLighting(Level.java:98)
at game.Level.generateMap(Level.java:58)
at game.Level.<init>(Level.java:21)
at game.mainClass.main(Minecraft.java:6)
```

please help if you know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude. Just use a 3D array.

```
int[][][] map = new int[width][height][depth];
```

Then you don't have to worry about demuxing `x`, `y`, and `z` indices from the `blockID`. They are lineary independent, so keep them that way.

Comment: @stas care to elaborate on that? In what regard is a 1D array with `w*h*d` elements "more efficient" than an equivalent 3D array?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private int getY(int blockID) {
    return (blockID / width) % height
}
```